# jQuery script re-starting on ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a javascript widget which updates a div with html from an external domain. It also intercepts any link clicks in this div and fetches fresh data, updating the div.

Issue I'm having is that when the link callback function runs after a click the JS script is re-run in it's entirety from `init()`.

In trying to debug it, in `handleClick()` if I hard-code the url the script runs once as expected e.g. `url: '/page-3/'`, but if I access the href from the clicked link e.g. `url: jQuery.attr('href')` the script re-runs. Is there any way of accessing this attribute without the script starting anew?

```js
"use strict";

(function () {
    var jQuery; //noconflict reference to jquery
    var serverFQDN = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000';
    var container = '#my-container';

    function init() {
        if (window.jQuery === undefined || window.jQuery.fn.jquery !== '3.4.1') {
       ...
    }

    function scriptLoadHandler() {
        // Restore $ and window.jQuery to their previous values and store the
     // new jQuery in our local jQuery variable
        jQuery = window.jQuery.noConflict();
        console.log('jQuery is now loaded');
        main();
    }

    function main() {
        jQuery(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery('head').append('<link href="' + serverFQDN + '/static/css/cleanslate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');
            jQuery('head').append('<link href="' + serverFQDN + '/widget.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">');

            jQuery(container).addClass('cleanslate');

            // build the initial widget
            jQuery.ajax({
                method: "GET",
                cache: false,
                url: "/page-1/",
                success: function (response) {
                    jQuery(container).html(response);
                    // handle clicks
                    jQuery(container + ' a').click(handleClick);
            }
        });
        });
    }


    function handleClick() {
        console.log('Intercepted link click');
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: jQuery.attr('href'),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('succesfully loaded external html');
                jQuery(container).html(response);
                jQuery(container + ' a').click(handleClick);
            }
        });
        // disable default click action
        return false;

    }


    init();


})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the `href` attribute you can use the `event` argument, provided by the Jquery click callback:

```
    function handleClick(event) {
        //you probably want this
        event.preventDefault();

        console.log('Intercepted link click');
        jQuery.ajax({
            method: "GET",
            cache: false,
            url: jQuery(event.target).attr('href'),
            success: function (response) {
                console.log('succesfully loaded external html');
                jQuery(container).html(response);
                jQuery(container + ' a').click(handleClick);
            }
        });
        // disable default click action
        return false;

    }
```

Comment: Thanks that works a charm. Also found out that `jQuery(this).attr('href')` works as well